# Oracle Assistance needed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains the list of merchants with two columns MerchantID and name.
Also i have two another tables trans1 and trans2 that contain the transactions done by these merchants.
What i need is an oracle query that lists these merchants with the SUM of the transactions in Trans1 and Trans2 tables as shown in the "Results" table

Merchants

```
================================
MerchantID         |      name
--------------------------------
1                   name 1
2                   name 2
3                   name 3
```

Trans1

```
=================================
MerchantID | Order ID   | Amount
---------------------------------
1        1            100
1        2            25
1        3            75
2        1            60
2        2            40
```

Trans2

```
===================================
MerchantID | Order ID   | Amount
-----------------------------------
1        1      100
1        2      50
1        3      50
2        1      25
2        2      25
3        1      30
```

Results

```
==========================================
id      | name      | total
------------------------------------------
1        name1      400
2        name2      150
3        name3      30
```

I tried UNION ALL with Inner JOIN however i didn't get the expected results

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a title that describes the problem; the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy-paste and execute not as unformatted tabular text); an English (not code) description of the logic that you want to implement; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and details of the expected output (formatted as a table using markdown). StackOverflow is not a free coding service; **YOU** need to attempt the problem first and then we can help with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you posted query you wrote (because, it looks as if you were on the right track).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  merchants (merchantid, name) as
  3    (select 1, 'name 1' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'name 2' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'name 3' from dual
  6    ),
  7  trans1 (merchantid, orderid, amount) as
  8    (select 1, 1,100 from dual union all
  9     select 1, 2, 25 from dual union all
 10     select 1, 3, 75 from dual union all
 11     select 2, 1, 60 from dual union all
 12     select 2, 2, 40 from dual
 13    ),
 14  trans2 (merchantid, orderid, amount) as
 15    (select 1, 1,100 from dual union all
 16     select 1, 2, 50 from dual union all
 17     select 1, 3, 50 from dual union all
 18     select 2, 1, 25 from dual union all
 19     select 2, 2, 25 from dual union all
 20     select 3, 1, 30 from dual
 21    ),
```

Query begins here: union of merchants and total amount per each of them in every trans table:

```
 22  trans as
 23    (select a.merchantid, sum(a.amount) amount from trans1 a group by a.merchantid
 24     union all
 25     select b.merchantid, sum(b.amount) amount from trans2 b group by b.merchantid
 26    )
```

Finally, just aggregate all amounts. Outer join is used in case you'd want to display rows from `merchants` table who don't have any orders yet:

```
 27  select m.merchantid, m.name, sum(t.amount) total
 28  from merchants m left join trans t on t.merchantid = m.merchantid
 29  group by m.merchantid, m.name;

MERCHANTID NAME        TOTAL
---------- ------ ----------
         1 name 1        400
         2 name 2        150
         3 name 3         30

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. However i have many records in each table; So what would be the final query? I just want to output the results and not adding them in a trans table.

Comment: Everything from line #22 to line #29. You'd just include WITH keyword at the beginning of line #22, i.e. `with trans as `.